# Why does nulling a variable during a method call make the value passed to the method null aswell?

Tags: java, methods, concurrency, parameters

I'm pretty confused about some java behavior, especially because my previous understanding of java was that it was strictly pass-by-value.

If I pass an object to a method, then null that object in the calling thread, I would expect the object would still exist and be able to be operated on in the method, but this is not the case.

Here is some sample code:

```java
public class methodTest {

    boolean bool;
    boolean secondBool;
    Test    list;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new methodTest().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        list = new Test();
        new Thread(() -> {
            func(list);
        }).start();
        list = null;
        bool = true;
        while (!secondBool) {
            // block
        }
        System.gc();
    }

    public void func(Test big) {
        while (!bool) {
            // block
        }
        System.out.println(big);
        secondBool = true;
    }

    class Test {
        @Override
        protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("I'm getting cleaned up!");
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Test!";
        }
    }
}
```

This code prints

```
null
I'm getting cleaned up!
```

when I would expect it to print:

```
Test!
I'm getting cleaned up!
```

I included the garbage collection call at the end and the finalize method in the class to ensure that the gc wasn't getting to the variable `list` before the function could print it, but the same effect occurs without it.

What is the explanation for this behavior?

EDIT:

Another example of this would be if you changed the `list = null` line in the run method to `list = new Test()`, then slightly modified the `toString` to count the number of `Test` instances. The program would print "Test2" instead of "Test1", because the value of the parameter in `func` was overridden in the calling thread, even though in my understanding of java's pass-by-value system, this should not happen.

Comment: It happens because the thread hasn't called `func()` yet at the moment you nulled `list`, so it received `null` when it did run. The real question here is why are you nulling `list`? Simple answer: don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prints null because there is a race condition and the new thread loses most of the time.

The timing is like this:

1. the main thread (the one running `methodTest.run()`) creates a new `Thread` object and starts the new thread (meaning it creates a new linux/windows thread and notifies it that it can start running)
2. as the very next step it sets the instance variable `list` to null
3. in parallel to the step 2 above the second thread starts running and eventually reaches the lambda `() -> { func(list); }`
4. only when the second thread executes `func(list);` will it read the instance variable `list`

What is passed as parameter `big` into `func` therefore entirely depends on

- how much time the main thread needs to execute `list = null;`
- how much time the os needs to start executing the second thread and for the second thread to reach the point where it calls `func(list);`

From your observation the second thread needs more time to reach the point where `func(list);` is executed than the main thread needs to execute `list = null;`

Comment: I didn't even think about the race between calling the function and setting `list` to null. I'm gonna do some testing and I'll get back to you.

Answer (score -2):

If I remember Java correctly, it changes the value for user defined classes. So if you use primitive data types and already defined classes like int, string, etc then it wont cause you this problem. But here you are using your own class so its passed by reference for some reason.